# Change html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, click

I need to change text on click in one div with jquery. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#hideall").click(function() {
$("#hideall").html("<p>SHOW</p>");
});
});
```

HTML is:

```
<div id="hideall" title="Hide all" name="Hide all">
<p>HIDE</p>
</div>
```

The problem is, it should be like div that shows state, when it's hidden, it shows

```
<p>SHOW</p>
```

and when it's showed it's

```
<p>HIDE</p>
```

I realized that should work with "if" function, but can't break it down. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a variable to check for this state,.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var isHidden = false; 
$("#hideall").click(function() {
if(isHidden){
    $(this).html("<p>SHOW</p>");
    isHidden = false;
}
else{
   $(this).html("<p>Hidden</p>");
   isHidden = true;
}
});//end click function
});//end ready
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hideall").toggle(function() {
        $(this).text('HIDE');
    }, function() {
        $(this).text('SHOW');
    });
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UN76V/**

Comment: he could also target the p with $("#hideall p")

Answer (score 0):

Or you can solve this issue using a class called hidden.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hideall").click(function() {
       if ($(this).is('.hidden') {
          $(this).removeClass('hidden').html("<p>SHOW</p>");
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('hidden').html("<p>HIDE</p>");
        }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#hideall").on('click', function () {
    var $p = $(this).find('p');
    var txt = 'SHOW';
    if ($p.text() === 'SHOW') {
      txt = 'HIDE';
    }
    $p.text(txt);
  });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zXBqA/)**